# Purpose of bitcoin mining puzzle

Tags: hash, cryptography, blockchain, bitcoin

I understand how Bitcoin mining requires a long effort to guess the nounce until one is able to produce hash with leading zeros.

I have two particular questions here --

1. Why is Bitcoin mining made so computationally expensive in the first place? If the purpose is to just choose a random winner for block placement, why not use a simple and faster proof-of-work algorithm? (one example could be to generate a random number between 0-1 and the one with the smallest/largest value wins the round). By making the puzzle less computationally expensive, we should save lot of electric energy globally.
2. Is there any specific advantage of choosing a puzzle to produce resulting hash with leading zeros?

Comment: #1). In addition to the below answers, the (increasing) work factor is one feature that distinguishes BitCoin from what governments do, namely just print more money. #2) Cryptographically, no, the K zero bits provide no advantage over any other fixed pattern of K bits at the beginning of the hash.

Comment: Could you please explain on why the work factor should be increased?

Comment: No. These questions should be asked on the bitcoin stackexchange site, except they have already been asked and answered. Please go there to find your answers.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

1. The difficulty of the algorithm is precisely what makes it difficult to cheat/steal on the Bitcoin network. If the algorithm was easy, then anyone could recreate old blocks and delete old spends so it looks like they never spent any Bitcoin after they buy something, for example. The purpose is not to pick a random winner, the purpose is to reward the miners doing the most work. It's true the winner is random, but the more work you do (more hashpower) the higher the probability that you will win. The probability is equal to the proportion of hashpower you're spending in relation to the total hashpower of the network.
2. Leading zeros is not what makes the hash valid, it just has to be under a threshold value. Leading zeros just happens because the number is low. It's like writing 1000 or 001000, it's still the same number, but the hash is 32 bytes so the leading zeros are there so you can see all 32 bytes.

I highly recommend reading the [Bitcoin Whitepaper](https://bitcoin.org/bitcoin.pdf) on proof-of-work. Also check out the [Bitcoin Wiki - PoW](https://en.bitcoin.it/wiki/Proof_of_work)

Comment: for 1. My understanding is that the complexity of compromising blockchain is due to chained hashing and controlling consensus majority. The mining puzzle should contribute to the complexity but not significantly.   I wonder if the purpose of the puzzle is to stabilize the bitcoin economy by controlling transaction rates.  



----
for the 2. I meant more along the line @President James wrote in the comment.

Comment: Ok I think I understand your question. The hash “puzzle” difficulty is set by the network and is called the network “difficulty”. The difficulty is a threshold the hash must be equal to or below. In other words, the difficulty basically sets how many leading zeroes the hash must have for the next block to be considered valid. This difficulty is set periodically (every 2 weeks) to keep the block generation time at 10 min on Bitcoin.  The more leading zeros, the harder (more hashpower required) it is to find a hash that is valid.